# PHP empty() not working as expected

Tags: php, forms, post, input

```
if(empty($_POST['name'])){
header("location:users_adduser.php?fail=1"); //no name specified
}
```

If I echo $_POST['name'] I can see that it is in fact empty.  So what gives?  How should I be checking for empty input fields?

Comment: What does `var_dump($_POST)` give you? Also, is error reporting turned on and do you get any errors?

Comment: http://zainal.wordpress.com/2006/04/25/8/

Comment: @Shack We can do better than that: [The Definitive Guide To PHP's isset And empty](http://kunststube.net/isset/) ;o)

Comment: further to Shackrock's comment, you might want to use trim() around $_POST['name'] to get rid of any white-space...which sounds like a prime culprit in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php), an empty string should be considered...well, empty.  I'd try using [var_dump()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) on $_POST and see what comes back, maybe it's not empty after all.

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

For testing purposes, comment out the header() call for now and perhaps just issue a print statement to ensure that it is actually evaluating to true.  It could be a header redirect issue rather than a problem with empty().

```
if(empty($_POST['name'])){
  // header("location:users_adduser.php?fail=1"); //no name specified
  print("POST['name'] IS empty!");
}
```

Comment: $_POST['name'] is set, but it's value is "" (if the text input is left blank).  According to the PHP manual (http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php), "" is considered to be empty.  But that's not happening... this seems like something that people would want to commonly check when getting input from forms, so there has got to be some easy way to do this.

Comment: Hi Danny, what were the var_dump() results?  It doesn't make sense for empty() to be behaving this way unless there was more than an empty string...In my experience whenever it has seemed like the language is doing something wrong, it turns out that there's something I've missed.

Comment: This was actually a mistake on my part.  The header calls were the issue.  Header was being changed later on down the page so even though empty() did evaluate to true I had some broken logic later on that set the header to something else.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
if (!isset($_POST['name'])){
header("location:users_adduser.php?fail=1"); //no name specified
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

Comment: It'd be nice if you could elaborate why `!isset` is supposedly preferable to `empty` here.

Comment: isset() will return true because $_POST['name'] is in fact set, the problem is that it's value is "".